# Looking for examples of a matrix lie group $G$ and some property of $G$ that is most easily seen by utilizing the corresponding Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

So the whole idea here is that Lie algebra's are supposed to be some sort of simplification, or linearization, or their corresponding Lie group. Can somebody give me examples of a matrix lie group $G$ and a property of $G$ that is most easily seen by utilizing the corresponding Lie algebra?

Thanks.

Comment: Groups such as $SO(n)$, $SU(n)$ can be easily seen to be compact since their Lie algebras are (i.e the Killing form is negative definite)

Comment: Moreover, in that case, the Killing form gives a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on the group

Comment: @Callum: proving that $SO(n)$ and $SU(n)$ are compact can be done very straightforwardly without any reference to Lie algebras, you just prove that they're closed and bounded subsets of $M_n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you have any examples for me??? I know you must!!

Comment: I've always found it somewhat easier to compute that the Lie algebras of upper triangular and strictly upper triangular matrices are solvable and nilpotent, respectively, than the corresponding assertions for the corresponding Lie groups $Id+ ...$.

Comment: I also think that the idea of *dimension* for a Lie group is somewhat more cumbersome to define rigorously than in the case of Lie algebras, where it is literally the basic concept of linear algebra. Likewise the formal definition of  *scalar extension* (e.g. complexification) of Lie groups looks discouraging to me, while on the LA level, it's just a plain old tensor product, a literal extension of scalars on a vector space.

Comment: Often the existence or non-existence of a  geometric structure on a Lie group $G$ can be shown much easier on the level of Lie algebras, e.g., left-invariant affine structures on $G$ via pre-Lie algebra structures on ${\rm Lie}(G)$. Of course, many structure results for $G$ follow easier for the Lie algebra using the Killing form or some other tool on the level of Lie algebras.