# Examples that Lie algebra is simpler to deal with than Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

When learning Lie group and Lie algebra, nearly all the books will state that dealing with Lie algebra will be simpler than with Lie group and this is one of the reasons why we will study Lie algebra. I can feel that dealing with Lie algebra will be easier since it's a vector space. But I wonder whether there is some simple example showing that when dealing with a problem, playing with Lie algebra will be easier than playing with a Lie group?

Comment: It is easier to show that there is no left-invariant affine structure on a semisimple Lie group by passing to the Lie algebra and use the first [Whitehead Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead%27s_lemma_(Lie_algebra))  for semisimple Lie algebras (over a field of characteristic zero). There are many more such examples. For example, problems of isospectral nimanifolds $N/\Gamma$ with nilpotent Lie group $N$ can be solved effectively by passing to the Lie algebra of $N$ and studying [almost inner derivations](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/dietrich.burde/masterthesis_verbeke_2016.pdf).

Comment: Very similar question asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4525589/96384

Comment: Usually we show that $SL_n(\Bbb C)$ is semisimple by showing that its Lie algebra has a nondegenerate Killing form, given by $B(x,y)=2n\cdot tr(xy)$. I suppose this is easier than to show it on the level of Lie groups, i.e., to show that it does not contain non-trivial connected solvable (or, equivalently, connected Abelian) normal subgroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very often geometric questions on Lie groups can be reduced to a problem on the level of Lie algebras, which is much more accessible then.

As an example, consider the question going back to Hermann Weyl,  whether or not isospectral manifolds are necessarily isometric.
Milnor gave a negative answer in 1964 by constructing two isospectral nonisometric flat tori in dimension 16. Later Gordon and Wilson
constructed isospectral but nonisometric compact Riemannian manifolds of the form $G/Γ$, with a simply connected exponential solvable Lie group G, and a discrete cocompact subgroup $Γ$ of $G$. A crucial tool there is the construction of interesting *almost inner automorphisms* of $G$. This can be transferred to *almost inner derivations* on the Lie algebra of $G$, and this is easier to study on the level of Lie algebras than on the level of Lie groups.

For details see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06159.pdf).